# Lookup Let's Encrypt expiry date when behind Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

My website uses an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt. The website also goes through Cloudflare. This means that the website uses Cloudflare's SSL certificate from the user's browser to Cloudflare and then it uses Let's Encrypt's from Cloudflare to the website server.

When I look up the website's SSL certificate in a browser then all I see is Cloudflare's SSL cert and its expiry date. This date is about 6 months in the future. However, I know that Let's Encrypt will expire much sooner than that, but when?

All methods that I have seen for looking up this date also only get the client-facing Cloudflare SSL cert date.

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect <website>:443 -servername <website> 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

I obviously need to know the (much sooner) date for when I need to renew the Let's Encrypt certificate. You know, so my website doesn't go down...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use localhost, not the domain.

This is how I run it from the Ubuntu, on the server where the Let's Encrypt certificate is stored.

```
 echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

If you have more than one certificate on the server, then this might work, but I'm not sure (I only have one):

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername <website> 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

This will also tell you the renewal dates if you installed the certificate with certbot:

```
certbot renew
```

Note that this will also renew the cert if less than 30 days are left.

Comment: The answer is not to use localhost but to use the real servers IP address or hostname which resolves to this IP address. This happens to be in your case localhost, but only since you've executed the command on the system itself. It will not work with localhost if you do it from a remote system.